# How can I use String Builder format my text file with StreamWriter?

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, stream, stringbuilder

Hello I have a StreamWriter Called gameWriter. Can I use string builder to format my Stream Writer? I want the result to look like this: playerOneName and playerTwoName are variables that need to be written. Can someone show me a sample code to show the following:

```
Output:
playerOnename, playerTwoname, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _,


private void WriteData(string playerOneName, string playerTwoName)
    {
        StreamWriter gameStateWriter = null;

        try
        {
            gameStateWriter = new StreamWriter(filepath, true);
            gameStateWriter.WriteLine(playerOneName + " , " + playerTwoName);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            txtOutcome.Text = "The following problem ocurred when writing to the file:\n"
               + ex.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (gameStateWriter != null)
                gameStateWriter.Close();
        }
    }
```

Yes those are underscores, they are suppose to represent spaces are ready to be written on to hold some text.

i am using Visual Studio '08 running ASP.NET website  and form.

Comment: Looks like something is missing... there is a random floating `string` in the middle of the try catch.  You can probably use `String.Format` for this... for example `String.Format("{0},{1},{2}", OneName, TwoName, ThreeName)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That how to use stream writer with string builder although i would recommend use a loop to append to builder.

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

builder.Append(playerOneName)
builder.Append(",")
builder.Append(playerTwoName)
builder.Append(",")
StreamWriter  nameWriter = new StreamWriter(filepath, true);
nameWriter.WriteLine(builder.ToString());
```

you just store all your variables in array

```
string[] names = {playerOneName, playerTwoName, playerThreName};
foreach(string item in names)
{

    builder.Append(item)
    builder.Append(",")
}
```

Comment: Oh please show me how to write a loop that can append to builder. If its not appended, it will overwrite my previous information.

Comment: look at example above, will it overwrite I think it all depends how you handle the file input